# Can the FB JS SDK be used to grab the referrer for your page in the FB iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I've been searching for quite a while on google and SO, but can't seem to find the answer on how, and I know it can be done (crazyegg.com seems to be able to pull in the referrer).  Does anyone know if using their JS SDK would allow me to do it?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details please? Referrer for what page? Are you talking about seeing the referrers that come to your canvas app? (http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp)

Comment: Not sure about the correct terminology but hopefully this describes it.  I have my site: some.page.com  and it's in a FB iframe: facebook.com/somepage

Then let's pretend someone clicked on a link to it from techcrunch.  How would I find out that techcrunch was the referrer?  Can I get that from the JS SDK?  Otherwise in the analytics it just shows the referrer as FB.  Thanks!

Comment: _“How would I find out that techcrunch was the referrer? ”_ – not at all, because the link on techchrunch would go to facebook.com/yourpage/sometab, and the user’s browser will send the referrer to that page only. _Your_ page get’s loaded into Facebook’s iframe afterwards, and the only referrer you might get – if any, browsers can handle this differently for framed content – then of course is facebook.com/…

Comment: [Cont.] The only chance of tracking external links to your page tab app is in a scenario where you have control over those links (giving them out to partner websites yourself) – then you can use the `app_data` parameter to pass a custom value through to your app (which can read it from the `signed_request` parameter).

Comment: You should have that as an answer CBroe :)